# Unable to read messages from kafka topic in ksqldb

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

```
{
 "event": {
  "header":{ 
   "name":"abc",
   "version":"1.0",
   "producer":"123",
   "channel":"lab",
   "countryCode":"US"
  },
  "body":{
   "customerIdentifiers":[ 
    {"customerIdentifier":"1234","customerIdType":"cc"},
    {"customerIdentifier":"234", "customerIdType":"id"}
   ],
   "accountIdentifiers":[
    {"accountIdentifier":"123",    "accountIdType":"no"}, 
    {"accountIdentifier":"Primary","accountIdType":"da"}
   ],
   "eventDetails":{
    "transactionDateTime":"2019-03-26 05:28:13.000",
    "transactionDate":"2019-03-26",
    "monthAverage":"188",
    "dailyAverage":"7"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Created stream for the above json:

```sql
CREATE STREAM STREAM_NAME(
  event STRUCT<
    header STRUCT<
      name VARCHAR,
      version VARCHAR,
      producer VARCHAR,
      channel VARCHAR,
      countryCode VARCHAR
      eventTimeStamp VARCHAR
    >,
    body STRUCT<
      customerIdentifiers STRUCT<
         customerIdentifier VARCHAR,
         customerIdType VARCHAR
      >,
      accountIdentifiers STRUCT<
         accountIdentifier VARCHAR,
         accountIdType VARCHAR
      >,                            
      eventDetails STRUCT<
         transactionDateTime VARCHAR,
         transactionDate VARCHAR,
         productDescription VARCHAR,
         monthAverage VARCHAR,
         dailyAverage VARCHAR
      >
    >
  >
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'TOPIC1',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
  PARTITIONS = 1
  ;
```

I mm  unable to read messages from stream:

```
select * from STREAM_NAME emit changes;
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: i see problem with below tags                                                                
 "customerIdentifiers":[{"customerIdentifier":"1234","customerIdType":"cc"},{"customerIdentifier":"234","customerIdType":"id"}],"accountIdentifiers":[{"accountIdentifier":"123","accountIdType":"no"},{"accountIdentifier":"Primary","accountIdType":"da"}]

Comment: I've submitted an edit to [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), which makes the question much more accessible to others.  Please do this yourself when asking future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running into deserialization errors because the schema of the stream you've created does not match the schema of your data.

Upon reformatting your example data and SQL the error becomes more easily apparent:

- The `$.event.body.customerIdentifiers` element is an array of structs, but the DDL defines it as a struct.
- The `$.event.body.accountIdentifiers` element is an array of structs, but the DDL defines it as a struct.

DDL that should work is:

```sql
CREATE STREAM STREAM_NAME(
  event STRUCT<
    header STRUCT<
      name VARCHAR,
      version VARCHAR,
      producer VARCHAR,
      channel VARCHAR,
      countryCode VARCHAR
      eventTimeStamp VARCHAR
    >,
    body STRUCT<
      customerIdentifiers ARRAY<STRUCT<
         customerIdentifier VARCHAR,
         customerIdType VARCHAR
      >>,
      accountIdentifiers ARRAY<STRUCT<
         accountIdentifier VARCHAR,
         accountIdType VARCHAR
      >>,                            
      eventDetails STRUCT<
         transactionDateTime VARCHAR,
         transactionDate VARCHAR,
         productDescription VARCHAR,
         monthAverage VARCHAR,
         dailyAverage VARCHAR
      >
    >
  >
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'TOPIC1',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
  PARTITIONS = 1
  ;
```

Also note the data does not contain the following, which are in the DDL, (though this shouldn't cause any issues, as the fields will just be `NULL`):

- `$.event.header.eventTimeStamp`
- `$.event.body.eventDetails.productDescription`

Comment: Is this better solutions than using EXTRACTJSONFIELD?

Comment: With extract json field I think you would create first stream with top level elements and second stream use create as to create the field names